# scaler.fit_transform return Incorrect information

Tags: python, scikit-learn

The dataframe sample is from:

https://pastebin.com/hQxWp9wZ

The test that does not pass is:

```
assert list(np.around(X_test_standard_scaled.max(axis=0), decimals=2)) == [1.61, 3.12, 3.3,
                                                                           2.97], 'Wrong scaled test values'
```

The values I get:

```
[1.53, 3.12, 2.97, 2.89]
```

I can not figure out what is wrong with the code:

```
def scale_test_features(X_test, scaler):
    if type(scaler) == type(MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))):
        return scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
    if type(scaler) == type(StandardScaler()):
        return scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

In the test set of the code I keep getting
`'Wrong scaled test values'`
But everything goes "by the book". Even after the repair done with saiden help,I'm still getting an error of 'Wrong scaled test values'. The other functions I use:

```
def scale_features(X_train, scale_type):
    if scale_type == 'minmax':
        min_max_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
        X_train_scaled= min_max_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        return min_max_scaler,X_train_scaled
    if  scale_type == 'standard':
        scaler = StandardScaler()
        X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
        return scaler,X_train_scaled
```

```
def split_to_train_and_test(X, y, test_ratio, rand_state):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_ratio, random_state=rand_state)
    return X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test
```

```
def load_dataset(file_name, label_column): 
    if len(file_name) != 0 and len(label_column) != 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        TRAINING_FEATURES = df.columns[df.columns != label_column]
        TARGET_FEATURE = label_column
        X = df[TRAINING_FEATURES]
        y = df[TARGET_FEATURE]
        return X,y
```

Can you tell me if the rest has a special error that can cause 'Wrong scaled test values'?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It doesn't make a lot of sense to check for `type` towards an object defined in the very same `if` statement. Plus, when assessing the type, the preferred method is `isinstance`.

Comment: I want to know the type of argument scaler (MinMaxScaler or StandardScaler)
and to scale X_test by the type

Comment: Please provide an example of the your input data as well as a traceback of the error.

Comment: @saiden
I added the DF and the values I am expected to receive but do not receive

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be the following. Please note that when probing for an object's class, the preferred method is `isinstance`, not `==`:

```py
def scale_test_features(X_test, scaler):
    if isinstance(scaler, MinMaxScaler):
        print('Using the Min-Max scaler')
        return scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
    elif isinstance(scaler, StandardScaler):
        print('Using the standard scaler'):
        return scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
```

Besides that, since your code lacks reproducibility I'm going to assume that when calling the split you didn't specify any `random_state`, which is why every time you call the function your dataset may end up with different values. Even so, I wouldn't complain too much about the values not being exactly the same, as they are already close enough.

On a side note, the code you provided is unnecessarely convoluted, here's few suggestions to improve it:

- The function `split_to_train_and_test` adds nothing on top of `train_test_split` already defined in scikit-learn, you could just as well call the original function, effectively improving readability.
- `ALL_CAPS` variable names are usually reserved for constants, like `pi`, see [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- Feature scaling *after* splitting is usually a poor idea, as you may bias your dataset depending on how the split happens: do it before splitting.
- In `scale_features` there is no need to also the scaler, as you are only interested in the scaled features.
- For the sake of encouraging help, please (please) try to post a question that anyone can copy-paste to their machine to debug, without any unnecessary, time-wasting, reverse engineering.

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the end I realized what my mistake was,i wrote```return scaler.transform(X_test)``` and I had to write ```X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)
    return X_test_scaled ```  What's interesting is why does it matter so much?